# including jquery.ui gives 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have my html something like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <link href="../../Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/elastic.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <input type="text" id="getText" placeholder="Enter text to search" onkeypress="setFocus(1)"
                onblur="setFocus(0)" />
            <input type="button" id="get" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" />
            <div id="smain">
            </div>
            <div id="smain1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and my javascript looks like this

```
function getSuggest() {
    var select = $("#select").val();
    var search = $('#getText');
    var text = search.val();
    $.post('/Home/Index', { "value": text, "svalue": select }, function (data) {
        $(data).each(function (index) {
            results += data[index];
            results += '<br/>';
        });
            $("#getText").autocomplete({
                  source:results
                    });

        results = '';
        if (focus == 1) setTimeout(function () { getSuggest() }, 300);
    });
}
```

I am using jquery.ui API for auto-complete function
when I execute this I am getting 400 bad request. I am new to this please with this

and my error looks something like this

```
    GET http://localhost:29908/Home/Lightwater%20Valley%3Cbr/%3EKitSound%20X-
Dock2%…20Connector%20Clock%20Radio%20Dock%20for%20iPhone
/iPod%3Cbr/%3E?term=light 400 (Bad Request)
```

Comment: That error indicates the problem lies in your `/Home/Index` endpoint on the server, not JS.

Comment: but when i dont't use autocomplete function it does not give any error

Comment: The the AJAX call `autocomplete` is making to get the data is causing the issue, either way a 400 error means the server is the problem. Check the request in the network tab of the console to find a descriptive error to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution and its working fine. Thanks for your suggestion @Rory McCrossan

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getText").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var select = $("#select").val();
            var search = $('#getText');
            var text = search.val();
            $("#smain").empty();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Index",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { "value": text, "svalue": select },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { value: item };
                    }))
                }
            })
        }
    });
})
```